# Output list by key in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I return a list from the view, and I want to output the specific value by key in the template.

returned list (list_)

```
[
{'category 1': 1},
{'category  2': 3},
{'category 3': 4}, 
]
```

In template:

`{{ list_.2.category 3}}`

returns 4.

Can I make the template tag simpler and output it just by the key?

For example:

`{{ list_.key['category 3'] }}`

My view:

```
def MapView(request):
    applications = Application.objects.values(
        'name', 'id', 'icon_name').filter(organization_id=1).order_by('name')
    devices = Device.objects.all()
    count_list = []

    for a in applications:
        count_num = devices.filter(id=a['id']).count()
        count_list.append({
            a['name']: count_num
        })

    context = {
        'test': count_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'applications/map.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `list` of `dict` to a `dict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import ChainMap

list_ = [{'category 1': 1}, {'category  2': 3}, {'category 3': 4}]
list_ = dict(ChainMap(*list_))
print(list_)
```

In Template:

```
{{ list_.category 3}}
```

**Note**: I have assumed you have unique keys.

---

Looks like you can  use `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

def MapView(request):
    applications = Application.objects.values(
        'name', 'id', 'icon_name').filter(organization_id=1).order_by('name')
    devices = Device.objects.all()
    count_list = defaultdict(int)

    for a in applications:
        count_list[a['name']]+= devices.filter(id=a['id']).count()

    context = {
        'test': count_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'applications/map.html', context)
```

Comment: I have added my view, i think i can change it to dictionary. I just want to append items to it. That's why i have used a list

Comment: Perfect. You answered my question. One small note. I need to concat list with another field in the loop. e.g. `test.a.name`  a.name is the loop iteration value. `for a in applications`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use square brakets in template but you can create custom [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

```
@register.simple_tag(name=access_lst)
def access_list_of_dicts(lst, index, key):
   return lst[index].get(key)
```

And use it in templates:

```
{% access_lst list 2 "category 3" %}
```